# Getting schema validation error for BreadcrumbList

Tags: seo, html, schema.org

For itemlistElement when the href is same as the URL, schema validator is throwing error

I have created an example to demonstrate the issue I'm facing.
Here is the link to example https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/b358b561-5812-403b-9fd9-7c76eec2a8a9

In the example for all the routes index.html is served. 
when the URL is `https://testing-schema.glitch.me/test` schema validator throws error however for any other URL it works fine.

Basically it is throwing error when the href is same as the URL.
I have attached 2 screenshots. One which works when href is different and URL is different and the other where it throws error.

I have tried many combinations, it only fails when the href(id) and the URL is same.
In the image attached. validator is giving error when the id is same as URL (https://testing-schema.glitch.me/test)

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool validator used

Comment: Just a guess. Maybe the message is misleading and meant to say that you can't have a self referencing breadcrumb. It doesn't make sense to add one anyhow. Unfortunately, Googles own examples imply you should!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be not able to get validation through Google Structured Data testing tool using RDFa, as currently.

If you want use inline markup, use standartized syntax - it will be validated errorfree, like

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" id="pageBreadCrumb">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
  itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="inactiveBread" id="breadcrumb_city_url">
      <a itemtype="https://schema.org/Thing"
   itemprop="item" href="/test">
      <span itemprop="name" > test </span></a>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
  </li>
  </ul>
```